# Add gutter to bootstrap flexbox grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to add gutters to a Bootstrap 4 site. I'm also using `enable-flexbox:true`;

I'm trying to achieve a look like http://designmodo.com/bootstrap-4-flexbox/: [image]

There are **equal** gutters on the bottom of each item, and to the right of each item.

My code is pretty simple:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-6 block'>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.block {
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
}
```

However, this doesn't create gutters. All the blocks are connecting. I realize I can put block as a new div under .col-md-4, but that ruins flexbox responsiveness.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

A simple method of changing bootstrap's default gutter size
http://arnique.net/web-design/58/a-quick-guide-to-changing-bootstraps-gutter-width/